# the first of string variables of struct can not receive input in Win32 Console Application in vs2015

Tags: c++, struct

string variables of struct can not receive input in Console Application in visual studio 2015 ,The problem is:when I run the app in console,the first variable always skipped and receive NULL。how should I fix this bug?

```
struct _comStrc
{
    char sNo[COM_PERO_LEN];
    char sType[COM_PERO_LEN];
    char sWhereCounter[COM_PERO_LEN];
    float price;
    int iTotal;
    long lDate;
};

    gets_s(m_comm.sNo,COM_PERO_LEN );

    gets_s(m_comm.sType, COM_PERO_LEN);

    gets_s(m_comm.sWhereCounter, COM_PERO_LEN);

    cin >> m_comm.price;

    cin >> m_comm.iTotal;

    cin >> m_comm.lDate;
```

Comment: Why are you mixing C and C++ inputs?  You should use `getline` for string input.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! I have tried getline(cin, m_comm.sNo) and cin.getline(m_comm.sNo, COM_PERO_LEN, '\n') ,all failed. But when I tried to write them at the same time ,it means that let the first variable m_comm.sNo get two times input ,now is OK.